# LCD display not wanting to update input (not displaying what I tell it to display)

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.4

I'm doing very basic PyQt so please excuse the poor optimization and lack of class orientation.

Im trying to make a timer in PyQt. I have 3 LCD's on the UI, an hour LCD (hourLcd), a minute LCD (minuteLcd) and a second LCD (secondLcd)

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import uic

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
#window = QtGui.QMainWindow()

ui = uic.loadUi("clock.ui")

#ui.setupUi(Window)
ui.show()
```

This sets up PyQt4

```
def hourUp():
    count = ui.hourLcd.value()
    if count < 24:
        count = count + 1
    ui.hourLcd.display(count)

def hourDown():
    count = ui.hourLcd.value()
    if count > 0:
        count = count - 1
    ui.hourLcd.display(count)

def minuteUp():
    count = ui.minuteLcd.value()
    if count < 59:
        count = count + 1
    ui.minuteLcd.display(count)

def minuteDown():
    count = ui.minuteLcd.value()
    if count > 0:
        count = count - 1
    ui.minuteLcd.display(count)

def secondUp():
    count = ui.secondLcd.value()
    if count < 59:
        count = count + 1
    ui.secondLcd.display(count)

def secondDown():
    count = ui.secondLcd.value()
    if count > 0:
        count = count - 1
    ui.secondLcd.display(count)
```

These are the functions for connecting the UI buttons to actions. e.g. if you press up button on the UI, it add's one to the counter

```
def start(stop):
    loop = False
    secondcounter = ui.secondLcd.value()
    minutecounter = ui.minuteLcd.value()
    hourcounter = ui.hourLcd.value()

    while loop == False:
        time.sleep(1)
        secondcounter = secondcounter - 1
        print(secondcounter)
        ui.secondLcd.display(secondcounter) ****

        if secondcounter == 0:
            if minutecounter != 0:
                minutecounter = minutecounter - 1
                print(minutecounter)
                ui.minuteLcd.display(minutecounter) ****
                secondcounter = secondcounter + 59
                ui.secondLcd.display(secondcounter) ****

        if secondcounter == 0:
            if minutecounter == 0:
                if hourcounter == 0:
                    loop = True

        if minutecounter == 0:
            if secondcounter == 0:
                if hourcounter != 0:
                    hourcounter = hourcounter - 1
                    print(hourcounter)
                    ui.hourLcd.display(hourcounter) ****
                    minutecounter = minutecounter + 59
                    print(minutecounter)
                    ui.minuteLcd.display(minutecounter) ****
                    secondcounter = secondcounter + 59
                    print(secondcounter)
                    ui.secondLcd.display(secondcounter) ****

        else:
            continue
```

The algorithm for making the timer work.

In basic, the code all works perfectly. It counts down to 0 from any time given, however I am having trouble linking the print outs of the code to the UI, specifically the line with stars next to them. 
I don't understand why the code is refusing to update the LCD digits when the counters change (e.g counter = counter - 1,) as it works in the other functions.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
 while loop == False:
    app.processEvents() #This was the line of code that I needed
    time.sleep(1)
    secondcounter = secondcounter - 1
    app.processEvents() #and this
    print(secondcounter)
    ui.secondLcd.display(secondcounter)
```

Basically, add app.processEvents() before you call your ui